# SQLAlchemy One-to-Many relation with repeated property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I will admit I am very new to SQLAlchemy and SQL in general. I am trying to get have a `Match` which references two `Players`, where `Player.matches` back references to any `Match` where they are either `Match.PlayerA` or `Match.PlayerB`.

```py
class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = "players"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    matches = relationship("Match")

class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = "matches"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    playerA_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("players.id"))
    playerB_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("players.id"))

    playerA = relationship("Player", foreign_keys=playerA_id, back_populates="matches")
    playerB = relationship("Player", foreign_keys=playerB_id, back_populates="matches")
```

The current error I cannot resolve:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join
> condition between parent/child tables on relationship Player.matches -
> there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the
> 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which
> should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent
> table.